# TortoiseSVN: Merge a different repository with similar structure into current WC (with local modifications)

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

Here's my situation: I have a checkout from a repository that has long since been moved to a different site. This working copy of mine is from an old revision of said repository, and there are local modifications as well. The author's method of moving the repository involved deleting the contents of the old repo, leaving a single text file named something along the lines of "MOVED", with instructions.

The new repository still has the same (or similar) structure. What I would like to do is "merge" (I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology) what is in the new repository with what I have in my working copy. I'm a little hesitant about doing this since I learned that TSVN will overwrite local changes without prompting me sometimes.

How can I go about merging the new repository in my local WC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to <kbd>Check Out</kbd> your "new" repository into another folder and overwrite the files with Copy-and-Paste. As the project structure was significantly modified, after overwriting this local copy, check file by file using <kbd>Diff</kbd> command.

At finishing, Commit the modifications and Update your other local copy. The local changes from this local copy won't be lost. The most that can happen is some conflicts.

Comment: But how to handle files deleted from the new repository

Comment: @GökhanKurt In this case, you'll need to delete manually the files on the new repository. There's no automatic solution.